# Adding days to a date via the ORM

Tags: python, django

How do you add days to a date in the database? My models are:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    days_due = models.IntegerField()
    issue_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

I have a function something like:

```
def is_due(self):
    time = self.days_due
    days = timedelta(days=time)
    due_date = self.issue_date + days
    if timezone.now() >= due_date:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I would like to be able to do something similar to the `is_due` function above with a database query, how would this be done?
I've referred to the documentation and could not see a way of combining the `F` class with `timedelta`s.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly, you can't do that with F expressions: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16487

You can either write a custom sql query using the *.raw()* method, or you can use standard filters to get this to work, but only if all your models have the same days_due value, which is probably not the case - but just in case, you can do it like this:

```
Item.objects.filter(issue_date__lte=now - datetime.timedelta(days=days))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do this in a db agnostic way. I would use an `extra(select)` to add a `is_due` field to your query. Something like (not tested):

```
Item.objects.extra(select={'is_due': 'issue_date + days_due'})
```

could work on a *postgres* database. Put the `extra select` in a custom manager to isolate the database specific code.